# Does a muslim have to change any of his/her natural beauty?

Tags: halal-haram, fitrah

Is it ever obligatory on a muslim man or woman to change any part of his/her body ? (other than trimming the nails, moustache or pubic hair)

For example, if a person has a natural hair which resembles one of the styles that the kuffar have, does he/she **have** to change the hairstyle or he/she can  keep it because they have this style naturally? (One of my cousins actually had a natural mohawk (almost))

Another example, say a non-Muslim women do a specific kind of change to their bodies to excessively beautify themselves. If a Muslim girl is born with that kind of beauty (the kind which the kuffar try to mimic), does she have to change that beauty because that resembles the kuffar?

Comment: -1, for the 2nd part. You need show a prove for this "if a female does a plastic surgery, then her daughter/son will be born with the new look"

Comment: @Sohaeb Umm, what? I didn't say that.

Comment: Ok, I will copy and paste what you said so you can prove it to me: "other example, say a non-Muslim women do a specific kind of change to their bodies to excessively beautify themselves. If a Muslim girl is born with that kind of beauty (the kind which the kuffar try to mimic)"

Comment: @Sohaeb What does that have to do with inheriting a surgery? I never said if a female does plastic surgery then her child will be born with that look. I think you just misunderstood or overthought. All I meant is, for example, if the kuffar women do a specific CUSTOM style (say a particular eyebrow style), and a Muslim girl has that style NATURALLY (given by Allah), then does she (the Muslim girl) have to change it because it resembles the style of the kuffar. Anyways, the accepted answer was good, you can read that for clarification.

Comment: Ok, you should have added this in your question which would help make it more understandable. Besides, why are over complicating and over thinking ? this -> "if the kuffar women do a specific CUSTOM style (say a particular eyebrow style), and a Muslim girl has that style NATURALLY (given by Allah), then does she (the Muslim girl) have to change it because it resembles the style of the kuffar"

Comment: @Sohaeb LOL, brother at no point in my question I mentioned a mother-daughter relationship. I don't see how more detailed I can make it to simplify things. Anyways, I guess we should not waste time arguing about this. We've got better things to do anyway.

Comment: Circumcision is considered obligatory for Muslim men ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/463)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Islamic sources forbid mutilating what Allah (swt) has given you. (In a permanent fashion such as getting a tattoo, or just generally artificially modifying yourself for no valid Islamic reason. (Please refer under sources for the hadith.)

**So directly addressing your question, your natural beauty is fine (since it is natural, including even if it looks like a non-Muslim).**

Take this argument for case:

Tattoo versus birthmark; the tattoo is haram because it is artificial and the birthmark is halal because it is natural. In Islam as far as I can find there is nothing against natural things.

## Sources:

> Narrated Ibn `Umar: 
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "**Allah has cursed such a lady as lengthens (her or someone else's) hair artificially or gets it lengthened, and also a lady who tattoos (herself or someone else) or gets herself tattooed.**" - [Sahih al-Bukhari 5937 Book 77, Hadith 152](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/152)